# Is there a simpler way to write this on one line in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following snippet that I m feeling it ugly and code repeatitive, is there any better way to achieve it more elegantly and performance freindly ?

```
            let id : number;
            if((<ParameterModel>this.activeNodeRule.node.data).parameterId){
                id = (<ParameterModel>this.activeNodeRule.node.data).parameterId
            }else{
                id = (<RuleModel>this.activeNodeRule.node.data).parameter.parameterId
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you already have a proper typing, ie `this.activeNodeRule.node.data` is already known to be of type `ParameterModel | RuleModel` at compiletime, I'd suggest to implement a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates). Then you can do something like the following

```
let data : ParameterModel | RuleModel = this.activeNodeRule.node.data;
let id = isParameterModel(data) ? data.parameterId : data.parameter.parameterId;
```

If you don't have proper typing, ie the type of `data` is entirely unknown at compiletime, you could do as follows:

```
let data = this.activeNodeRule.node.data as unknown;
let id: number;
if (isParameterModel(data)) id = data.parameterId;
else if (isRuleModel(data)) id = data.parameter.parameterId;
else //do whatever needs to be done, if data is any other type.
```

This IMHO is the cleanest way to deal with such a situation. Good code is not always about being as short as possible, but also should be readable and understandable ...

Comment: yes it is compile time type defined :)

Comment: I feel this is the best answer, Cuz it help me to externilize the validation logic, Thanks @derpirscher

Comment: I totaly agree for your last sentence it what I was asking for but words betrayed me

Answer (score 2):

What is the type of `data`. Is it `ParameterModel | RuleModel`? Does `parameterId` not exist on `RuleModel`? Assuming those two, you can do something like:

```
const data = this.activeNodeRule.node.data;
const id = 'parameterId' in data ? data.parameterId : data.parameter.parameterId;
```

Depending on your TS config, the other answers might only work if `parameterId` also exists on `RuleModel`.

**Edit:** Actually, if you can, do the type predicate. It's better.

Comment: sometimes it type is ParameterModel and other times is RuleModel

Answer (score 1):

If you need validate first if `parameterId` exists and if not asign `parameter.parameterId`

```
id = (<ParameterModel>this.activeNodeRule.node.data).parameterId?(<ParameterModel>this.activeNodeRule.node.data).parameterId:(<RuleModel>this.activeNodeRule.node.data).parameter.parameterId
```

if you can validate first `parameter`

```
id = (<ParameterModel>this.activeNodeRule.node.data).parameter?.parameterId
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
const data = this.activeNodeRule.node.data
const id = data?.parameterId ?? data?.parameter?.parameterId
```

This might not be type-safe depending on your context though, you may have to add a bang `!` somewhere.